# It is very slow to sync by parity in archive mode

Tags: parity

I am syncing by parity in archive mode.

> tracing="on" pruning="archive" fat_db="on"

Currently it is around 4,880,000 blocks but very slow, 0.2~0.8 blk/s. 
I am afraid it will take serveral months to the latest block (>8,000,000 blocks).
How can I make it faster?

Comment: what is your node's hardware configuration?